# Создание отчёта WinForm C#

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, report

Здравствуйте!
При попытке создание отчёта с помощью запроса sql в ReportViewer ничего не отображается. 
Какие могут быть причины?
Как можно заполнить ReportViewer без rdlc файла? 
Или как отобразить результаты sql запроса в ReportViewer?
Код:

```
            connect.OpenConnection();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM supermarket.stock;";
            connect.command = new MySqlCommand(query, connect.connection);
            connect.adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(connect.command) {SelectCommand = connect.command};
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable.TableName = "myDataTable";
            dataTable.Clear();
            //connect.adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            //DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            //connect.adapter.Fill(dataSet);
            //DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
            connect.CloseConnection();

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); //clear report
            ReportDataSource dataset = new ReportDataSource(dataTable.TableName, dataTable); // set the datasource
            dataset.Value = dataTable;
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataset);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Administrator_company.Preview__Test_.MyReport.rdlc";

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Вот сам результат выполнения:

[image: При загрузке ничего не отображается]

Comment: Так rdlc файл содержит шаблон формы отчета. Возможно форму можно загрузить через Stream - но без шаблона вы отчёт не увидете точно.

Comment: @nick_n_a Что мне тогда следует предпринять?

Comment: @AndreyKogut, нужно создать rdlc файл. это можно сделать с помощью программки Report Builder. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519551.aspx Когда-то делал так, если найду проект, напишу решениение. Сейчас пользуюсь Crystal Reports для построения отчетов

Comment: @PleshkovIvan спасибо!
Как решение можно создать отчёт в виде PDF файла, использовать для этого iText.

Comment: @AndreyKogut, это конечно вариант, но на крайний случай (хотя конечно зависит от отчета). CR позволяет пользователю выбирать, в каком формате сохранять: xls, doc, pdf, и т.д. Если я правильно помню, то используемый вами Report Viewer тоже это позволяет. Предоставляя отчет только в pdf вы лишите пользователей этого выбора. Хотя, если отчет содержит много графики, много различных таблиц, это может быть оправдано

Comment: @PleshkovIvan, полностью с вами согласен. Но этот вариант (с отчётом в виде pdf файла) для меня показался наиболее быстрым и оптимальным.
Хотелось бы также решить вопрос с Report Viewer.